# SwiftUI: State Not Updating From Child View's Binding

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view that has a `TextField()`, that when tapped will display a [child view](https://github.com/Mijick/PopupView) with pre-defined roles. The user will then tap a pre-defined role, which updates a `@Binding` and dismisses the child. After the child is dismissed, the text field does not reflect the selected role until it is tapped on a second time.

I have tried making the `user` variable a `@State` and a `@StateObject` to no avail. I even tried making it `@Binding`. Any help would be appreciated.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PopupView

struct RegisterUserScreen: View {
    @State private var members: [UserModel] = []
    @State private var selectedMember: UserModel
    @State private var selectedRole: String = ""

    @FocusState private var roleFocused: Bool

    @State private var user: UserViewModel

    init(for user: UserViewModel) {
        self.user = user
        self.selectedMember = user.model
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Role")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            TextField("", text: $selectedMember.role)
            .padding()
            .background(.gray.opacity(0.25))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .focused($roleFocused)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 64)
        .onChange(of: roleFocused) { _ in
            if roleFocused {
                RolePopup(role: $selectedMember.role)
                .showAndReplace()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension RegisterUserScreen {
    func makeCircle(for userModel: UserModel) -> some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .opacity(selectedMember == userModel ? 1 : 0.65)
            .onTapGesture { selectedMember = userModel }
    }
}

struct RegisterUserScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Preview()
    }

    struct Preview: View {
        @StateObject private var user = UserViewModel()

        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                RegisterUserScreen(for: user)
                    .implementPopupView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child View:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PopupView

struct RolePopup: CentrePopup {
    @Binding var role: String

    let roles: [String] = ["Father", "Mother", "Son", "Daughter", "Roommate", "Partner"]

    func createContent() -> some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Select Role")
                    .font(.title.weight(.bold))

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 2)
            }
            .padding()

            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                ForEach (roles, id: \.self) { role in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.role = role
                        dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            if self.role == role {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                    .background {
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(.green)
                                    }
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "circle")
                            }

                            Text(role)
                                .font(.body.weight(.bold))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 12)
            .padding(.bottom, 48)
            .padding(.horizontal, 48)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.primaryText)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .fill(.secondaryBackground)

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .stroke(.white)
        }
    }

    func configurePopup(popup: CentrePopupConfig) -> CentrePopupConfig {
        popup
            .backgroundColour(.clear)
            .horizontalPadding(28)
            .tapOutsideToDismiss(true)
    }
}
```

UserModel:

```swift
import Foundation

final class UserModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published public var admin: Bool
    @Published public var age: String?
    @Published public var name: String
    @Published public var familyName: String
    @Published public var photo: NSData?
    @Published public var role: String
    @Published public var tintAlpha: Float?
    @Published public var tintBlue: Float?
    @Published public var tintGreen: Float?
    @Published public var tintRed: Float?
    @Published public var username: String

    internal init() {
        self.admin = false
        self.age = nil
        self.familyName = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.photo = nil
        self.role = ""
        self.tintAlpha = nil
        self.tintBlue = nil
        self.tintGreen = nil
        self.tintRed = nil
        self.username = ""
    }
}

extension UserModel: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: UserModel, rhs: UserModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is wrong. `UserModel` (why not simply `User`) is supposed to be a **struct** which *publishes* its members automatically on change if it's declared as `@State`. And `UserViewModel` which is clearly a class must conform to `ObservableObject` and be declared as `@StateObject`. Consider also that you cannot initialize `@State` and `@StateObject` properties directly in `init`. You have to set their `wrappedValue` or `initialValue`.

Comment: Best take a moment to learn `View`, `@State` and `@Binding`

Comment: @vadian Ok, I now pass `UserViewModel` using `@EnvironmentObject` from its parent. I also changed `UserModel` to be a struct and use `@State`. The `selectedMember` is meant to default to `UserViewModel.UserModel`, so when I try to use `self._selectedMember = State(initialValue: user.model)`, I get `Variable 'self.selectedMember' used before being initialized` (I kind of understand why, due to how Swift inits things). What is the better way to achieve this? I apologize for being new, but I'm lost.

Comment: @malhal I'm open to any good resources that are beginner friendly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need `selectedMember` to be an [ObservedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject)

```
@ObservedObject private var selectedMember: UserModel
```

Comment: I did try that after I posted, and it didn't work either. What @vadian said in their comment on my post I think makes more sense (using struct for UserModel instead of class). Thank you though!